# Do and Make contextual explanation

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, do-vs-make

I've come up with these sentences :

> do or make these updates

.
And I don't know which one to choose.
Any explanation will be really appreciated on why I should use one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct phrase is "make these updates" but I couldn't give an explanation. If you wanted to tell someone to update something you could also use the verb itself. For example,  "Please update this document to include purchases from 2015."